# SSL Certificate errors for both pip and maven on OS/X Sierra

Tags: ssl, certificate

SSL Certificate problems are occurring on at least two unrelated types of processes: building apps for `python/pip` and a `scala/java` app (`spark`) using `maven`.

This is occurring on a brand new/fresh Macbook pro with Sierra.

Here is the first one: `pip`:

```
    $pip install numpy
    Collecting numpy
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I had not encountered this issue on other systems/machines. I followed the suggestion here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32302448/1056563 . But adding the `--cert path_to_cert` had no effect

Second example:  I did a  `git clone` of `Spark` and was attempting to build it as shown:

```
$./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.7 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

It failed immediately with certificate errors:

```
Using `mvn` from path: /usr/local/bin/mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/14/apache-14.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.spark:spark-parent_2.11:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:14 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 11
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.spark:spark-parent_2.11:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT (/shared/spark/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.spark:spark-parent_2.11:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:14 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I have looked at apparently similar questions but none have fit my particular circumstances:  e.g there appears to be a valid certificate in the JRE/JDK:

```
$ll /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel  113484 Mar 15 01:51 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***KASPERSKY ENDPOINT SECURITY***

By disabling it temporarily - while installing pip / building via maven - the problem disappears.